# IIO Linux: notify another driver when samples are ready

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, iio

I have a driver for the LSM6DSOX provided by ST which can be configured to use hardware interrupts and read data. I see that IIO interface is exposed to the user space but I need this data in the another driver.
I think that implementation of the hwmon may be quite good and shows what I wanted to achieve, the example code I found is here https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hwmon/iio_hwmon.c so I can find a GYRO channels and read samples but in this case hwmon needs to call "iio_read_channel_processed" to get sample.

My problem is that I don't know when I should call "iio_read_channel_processed" because I wanted to be notified by the IIO that the sample is ready to read. I expected that I could pass some callback function that will be called each time IIO buffer will receive new sample from another driver. Is that possible?

Comment: inter module communication - there is a lot of help on internet

Comment: but in that case I will need to modify driver provided by manufacturer which reads data from gyro and put them into IIO. I don't want to modify that driver I just want to create my driver that can read samples from a gyro installed in the system. If I will need to use another chip in the future I just wanted to replace gyro driver only without code modifications.

Comment: Why not to ask in linux-iio@ mailing list? Jonathan is a kind guy, he helps newbies.

Comment: It seems what you are looking for is **IIO_BUFFER_CB** (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/buffer/Kconfig#L7): "IIO callback buffer used for push in-kernel interfaces" Should be selected by any drivers that do in-kernel push usage.  That is, those where the data is pushed to the consumer.